# itext java struts 1 getting error when trying to add table in document.add(table)

Tags: java, itext, struts1

```
try
{
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("sns/home/Desktop/ab.pdf"));
  document.open();
  PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(3);
  PdfPCell cell1=new PdfPCell(new com.lowagie.text.Paragraph("cell1"));
  PdfPCell cell2=new PdfPCell(new com.lowagie.text.Paragraph("cell2"));
  PdfPCell cell3=new PdfPCell(new com.lowagie.text.Paragraph("cell3"));
  table.addCell(cell1);
  table.addCell(cell2);
  table.addCell(cell3);
  document.add(table);//method add in class document cannot be applied to given types, Required element found PdfPtable.
  document.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: please add the error you are getting

Comment: error is commented on the line , document.add(table)

Comment: what version of itextpdf are you using? might be because of the version you are using. The same code works fine for me (itextpdf 5.2.1 ) and here is the code : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/table.html

Comment: balaji i tried this but it not working

Comment: your itextPDF version ?

Comment: The PdfPTable that i used is com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable class. I doubt you are using other jars which also contain the PdfPTable (bcoz the para u used com.lowagie.text.Paragraph is not in itext pdf 5.3.0) and you must have used PdfPTable class from another jar.Can you check the PdfPTable import is com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable